# Want to pause/resume grabba scan for specific time. Using Android grabba sdk

Tags: java, android

I am using android grabba sdk for scanning barcodes. When I scan the barcode publish the result on the screen. I wanted to pause scanning operation for 3 sec and after that, I want to resume again scan. So can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Sorry this can be Ask only grabba support team